# Altium: unable to import from schematic

Tags: altium

I have completed an Altium PCB design and now I want to change the footprint of one component. The "Import Changes from " button is inactive. How can this be enabled?

[image]

Comment: Can you be little more specific? What do you need and what is a problem?

Comment: ı wanna import changing from shematic to PCB. But it is inactive. What is reason of problem and how can ı solve problem

Comment: Try to update it from schematic editor. In schematic editor click Design->Update PCB Document...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your documents are listed under "Free Documents", meaning they have not been added to a project. In order to fix this, go to File --> New --> Project, select PCB project and give it a name/location.

[image]
[image]

Once your project is created, right-click it in the projects panel, select "Add existing to project".

[image]

Then add your schematic and PCB files to it. 
Once you do that, you should be able to import changes from the schematic into the PCB.

Comment: I overlooked this feature. problem is solved, Thank you for consideration.

Comment: If this is the correct answer and it solved your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted". Thanks! =)